# ABPeoplePickerNavigationController Class Reference

Tags: objective-c, ios8, abpeoplepickerview

`peoplePickerNavigationController:shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:` is deprecated in iOS 8. Does anyone know the substitute method?

Comment: See the iOS 8 release notes under the Contacts section.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your app only requires user to select from list and not display details. peoplePickerNavigationController:didSelectPerson: is the replacement method.

```
- (void)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker didSelectPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{

    ...
}
```